# Div resize with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, resize

I have a Drawer navigation and I am trying to implement mouse drag resize option.
I added a div element on which I listen onMouseDown event.
and when this event happens I add an event listener for mouseup event to update my drawers width when I release the mouse.

```
const handleMouseDown = (event: MouseEvent) => {
  document.addEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp)
}

const handleMouseUp = (event: any) => {
    const minWidth = 57
    const maxWidth = 600
    if (event.clientX > minWidth && event.clientX < maxWidth) {
      updateLayout({ ...layout, drawerWidth: event.clientX })
    }
  }

<Dragger onMouseDownCapture={handleMouseDown}/>
```

Everything works fine on the first try, but after that the mouseDown event does not add the mouseup event listener.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to remove the `mouseup` event listener after each mouse up else the event listener will stacks multiple times and cause issue.

```js
const handleMouseUp = (event: any) => {
    const minWidth = 57
    const maxWidth = 600
    if (event.clientX > minWidth && event.clientX < maxWidth) {
        updateLayout({ ...layout, drawerWidth: event.clientX })
    }
    document.removeEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp)
}
```

Comment: You are right. I am going to do that of course, but I did not included it in question code, because it is not related to my question.

Comment: Perhaps you can show more codes on your `Dragger` component ? especially the `onMouseDownCapture` props.

Comment: Dragger component is just a div. No logic there

Comment: Need more context, please provide as much codes as possible